# Comparing between rows in same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, compare

I am trying to find the best way to compare between rows in the same table.
I wrote a self join query and was able to pull out the ones where the rates are different. Now I need to find out if the rates increased or decreased. If the rates increased, it's an issue. If it decreased, then there is no issue.

My data looks like this

```
ID       DATE           RATE
1010     02/02/2014      7.4
1010     03/02/2014      7.4
1010     04/02/2014      4.9
2010     02/02/2014      4.9
2010     03/02/2014      7.4
2010     04/02/2014      7.4
```

So in my table, I should be able to code ID 1010 as 0 (no issue) and 2010 as 1 (issue) because the rate went up from feb to apr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a select..case

```
select case when a.rate > b.rate then 'issue' else 'no issue' end
from yourTable a
join yourTable b using(id)
where a.date > b.date
```

See [documentation for CASE expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm).

Comment: That would pick up decreases in rates as well.

Comment: Thank you all. Is there any way we could code all the IDs as 'Issue' if any one of them is an issue? That way I can filter and get all the records with different dates for the ID with Issues rather than just one or two records. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a case for `LAG()`:

```
with sample_data as (select 1010 id, to_date('02/02/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 7.4 rate from dual union all
                     select 1010 id, to_date('03/02/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 7.4 rate from dual union all
                     select 1010 id, to_date('04/02/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 4.9 rate from dual union all
                     select 2010 id, to_date('02/02/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 4.9 rate from dual union all
                     select 2010 id, to_date('03/02/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 7.4 rate from dual union all
                     select 2010 id, to_date('04/02/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') dt, 7.4 rate from dual)
select id,
       dt,
       rate,
       case when rate > lag(rate, 1, rate) over (partition by id order by dt) then 1 else 0 end issue
from   sample_data;

        ID DT               RATE      ISSUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      1010 02/02/2014        7.4          0
      1010 03/02/2014        7.4          0
      1010 04/02/2014        4.9          0
      2010 02/02/2014        4.9          0
      2010 03/02/2014        7.4          1
      2010 04/02/2014        7.4          0
```

You may want to throw an outer query around that to only display rows that have `issue = 1`, or perhaps an aggregate query to retrieve id's that have at least one row that has `issue = 1`, depending on your actual requirements. Hopefully the above is enough for you to work out how to get what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct ID from MyData latest
inner join MyData earlier on latest.id = earlier.id
where earlier.date < latest.date and earlier.rate < latest.rate
```

would be one way to get them unless you really need to select those with no issues?

Answer (score 0):

select a.&, case when a.rate > b.rate then 'issue' else 'no issue' end
from table a
join table b on a.ID=b.ID
where a.date > b.date;