# Comparing data and dates in plsql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table as:

```
date_stmp     ticker_name    a_clos_prc   b_clos_prc
05/20/17      APPL           $300.60      $300.60
05/21/17      APPL                        $300.61
```

Is there a way to check to see IF `b_clos_prc` is the same as the day before if `a_clos_prc` is missing data AND `b_clos_prc` has data?

So for the example, the result would look like this:

```
 date_stmp   ticker_name     a_clos_prc   b_clos_prc   Diff
 05/20/17    APPL            $300.60      $300.60
 05/21/17    APPL                         $300.61     +0.01
```

I am stuck on how to come up with the logic for this.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: As pointed out by Gordon, you need to provide expected results and be specific and clear about your requirements in order for the others to help you.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure for that?

Comment: by stored do you mean the alias?

Comment: No, horse is asking why you need a PL/SQL procedure to do this when most probably it could be achieved in SQL.

Comment: Have a look at the [`lag`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/lag-lead-analytic-functions) SQL function. No need for PL/SQL.

Comment: that's is what I ended up using. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
  from table a2, table a1
 where trunc(a1.date_stmp) - 1 = trunc(a2.date_stmp)
   and (a1.a_clos_prc = a2.b_clos_prc  or (a1.a_clos_prc is null and  a2.b_clos_prc is null ))
```

Comment: its is all under one table. I see that you have two tables. is there a way to do it when its all under one table?

Comment: a2 and a1 are same table used twice in order to compare values in different rows.

Comment: you can check other comparisons but all uses same table twice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815811/comparing-between-rows-in-same-table-in-oracle

Comment: ok. so in order for this to work I have to create an alias table to work with

Comment: The only issue with this code is that you cant call where when creating aliases. It has to be nested somehow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146070/discussion-between-user7294900-and-user-123945839432).